# Fatal error: Array index out of range

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

**My Situation:**

There is an array called `friendCardList` claimed in the `AppDelegate.swift`, and the `CardModel` is just normal class :

```
var friendCardList:[CardModel] = []
```

In a `UITableViewController` called `FriendListVC`, the elements in the array `friendCardList` will be listed in the `FriendListVC`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let card = delegate.exchangeListCards[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CardsCell",
    forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BrowserTableViewCell
    return cell
}
```

I was trying to delete the cell in the `FriendListVC`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let card = delegate.exchangeListCards[indexPath.row]
    var CardSet = NSMutableSet(array: delegate.exchangeListCards)
    CardSet.removeObject(card)
    delegate.exchangeListCards = CardSet.allObjects as! [CardModel]
}
```

My Problem:

When I deleted the cell through sliding the cell to the left, the complier thrown the bug:

```
fatal error: Array index out of range
```

[image]

I blocked up here all the noon.

Comment: Hint: You removed the data from array, but your tableview doesn't know that. You need to inform your tableview about the dataset change.!!!

Comment: @MidhunMP I'm dealing with a similar error, how do you inform the tableview of the change? I have used self.reloadData() in my code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call

```
self.reloadData()
```

in your UITableViewController each time you modify your data source.

Comment: Thank you very much. Bug went away when I added `self.reloadData( )`.

Comment: @EthanJoe: I won't recommend this. Reloading entire tableview is not a good practice. You can use deleteRowAtIndexPaths method instead. Check this tutorial http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/delete-rows-from-tableview